# How to access encrypted Linux user from Windows?

Tags: linux, ssd, encryption, linux-mint

I'm trying to access my backup from an SSD with Linux Mint on it, but my user is password-protected and encrypted. I have tried numerous methods to try and input the password, but nothing has worked and neither has booting from a live USB. (I was using encryptfs on the USB.) Fiddling with BIOS settings is quite tedious, and not something I'd want to do.

Any good advice?

Comment: Did you already try this tutorial step-by-step? **[How to Recover an Encrypted Home Directory on Ubuntu]**(https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Gave me an error, and isn't gksu deprecated?

Comment: Please, inform on the question the full error description.

Comment: Your question needs clarification. There is no such thing as an encrypted user in Linux (A users homedir yes, but if you boot from a disk then its just a directory). This would not have anything to do with BIOS. (It could conceivably be TPM related but this is HIGHLY unlikely and fiddling with the BIOS can't help here).

Comment: Also, what version of Mint? I think mint used ecryptfs (different to encfs) Have you found the encrypted filesystem? Are there any hidden files on it? (Encfs uses a file .encfs for example)

Comment: I meant a homedir, my mistake. I'm using Cinnamon, and I found no hidden files. Don't remember the error, sadly.